# Interpolate a string from values that come from another module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a module like this in its own file in my "**models**" folder:

```
module IntervalUnits
  VALUES = [MONTHLY, QUARTERLY, YEARLY].freeze

  MONTHLY = 0
  QUARTERLY = 1
  YEARLY = 2
end
```

Then in my "**helpers**" folder I have another file that somewhere on a RaiseError I also want to show those VALUES from the file above.  How can I do that?

I know that string interpolation is like this `"#{stuff}"` but not sure how to do that when it is a array of those constants that I am reading from another file like the one above that I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to define your constants before you assign them to an array. Otherwise, you will get an exception like:

> NameError: uninitialized constant IntervalUnits::MONTHLY

After reordering your variable declarations, just reference your constants using the module's namespace. For example:

```
module IntervalUnits
  MONTHLY   = 0
  QUARTERLY = 1
  YEARLY    = 2

  VALUES    = [MONTHLY, QUARTERLY, YEARLY].freeze
end

IntervalUnits::VALUES
# => [0, 1, 2]
```